# Using Malloc() to create an integer array using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, abstract-data-type

I'm trying to create an integer array using the defined ADT below using the malloc() function. I want it to return a pointer to a newly allocated integer array of type intarr_t. If it doesn't work - I want it to return a null pointer.

This is what I have so far -

```
//The ADT structure

typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;

//the function 

intarr_t* intarr_create( unsigned int len ){

    intarr_t* ia = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t)*len);
    if (ia == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Warning: failed to allocate memory for an image structure\n" ); 
            return 0;
        }
    return ia;
}
```

The test from our system is giving me this error

```
intarr_create(): null pointer in the structure's data field
stderr 
(empty)
```

Where abouts have I gone wrong here?

Comment: I think the purpose is to allocate memory dynamically for the *member* `data` in the structure.

Comment: You're allocating space for a bunch of `intarr_t` elements ... but what about allocating space for the `int * data` field in each element????  And what about initializing all the fields for each element???

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm not very familiar with using malloc and typedefs like this yet. =/

Comment: Allocate *one* `intarr_t` structure, then initialize `len` integers for the `data` member. I leave it as an exercise for you what you should initialize the `len` structure member as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be inferred from the error message, `intarr_create(): null pointer in the structure's data field`, that `data` fields of each struct are expected to be allocated.

```
intarr_t* intarr_create(size_t len){
    intarr_t* ia = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t) * len);
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // ia[len].len = 0; // You can initialise the len field if you want
        ia[len].data = malloc(sizeof(int) * 80); // 80 just for example
        if (ia[len].data == 0)
        {
            fputs("Warning: failed to allocate memory for an image structure", stderr); 
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return ia; // Check whether the return value is 0 in the caller function
}
```

Comment: Theres nothing in the for loop that gets iterated on since i isn't used anywhere,  is that by design?

Comment: @Code_Penguin Ops it's my bad. I forgot to declare `i`. Edited mow.

Comment: So your for loop is just creating memory of size int for each data member in ia of size len, len times?

Comment: @Code_Penguin Yes.

Comment: What purpose does the * 80 serve?

Comment: @Code_Penguin `data` is a "pointer to `int`", so it is assumed that the `data` field of each struct should point to a block of memory that can hold 80 elements of type `int`. Without that `80`, each `data` field can only hold one `int` element.